# Auto update cart on quantity change in Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a $5 fee that gets added to the order total when using lets say "Cash on Delivery". This fee should be removed when switching to "bank transfer". This fee gets removed just fine when I trigger the order review table to update by lets say changing the billing zip code. But I need it to also trigger when selecting a different payment gateway.

Here is my current code:

```
<script>
    $('#payment_method_bacs').on('click', function() {
    $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );})
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make this question somewhat useful for anyone who reads here in the future.. here is the script that ended up working for me. I found the answer here from this [helpful guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-automatically-update-cart-quantity-change/).

```
    jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('click', 'input.qty', function(){ 

        jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this to update cart via AJAX. Here is the [link](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-modify-the-cart-details-on-woocommerce-checkout-page/)

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
    $( "form.checkout" ).on( "click", "input.qty", function( e ) {//modify this to payment gateway radio button selection
      var data = {
      action: 'update_order_review',
      security: wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce,
      post_data: $( 'form.checkout' ).serialize()
    };

    jQuery.post( add_quantity.ajax_url, data, function( response )
    {
      $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
    });
  });
});
```

Here in above code instead of quantity update, Just add your change event of  payement Gateway radio button selection

Comment: Do you want this to work on Order review Table, Then there is some change

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please refer that above link

Comment: @BrennanWalsh. First check that error, why jQuery is not working. The above link is the best and standard way to do

Answer (score 0):

Since this part (payment methods) of the checkout being updated in the background, you should bind the click to "body" such as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('click', 'ul.payment_methods li', function(){
            console.log('payment method clicked');
    });
});
```

(Untested!)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid customer click so many time make ajax call so many time:

```
 jQuery( function( $ ) {
    let timeout;
    $('body').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){
        if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
        }, 800 );
    });
} );
```